# Read out semicolon separated text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to save data from a text file in a Temp table.
The text file looks like this:

```
1000132;1000151;1000149;1000150;1000152;1000153;1000154;1000155
```

How can I read out a text file and save the data into rows?

Comment: What tool and database are you using?

Comment: [Different Options for Importing Data into SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1207/different-options-for-importing-data-into-sql-server/)